# Why won't my shower fully heat up?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, thermostat, temperature

I have a thermostatic shower, but I can only get it to be luke warm. The aquastat is set at 60, boiler at 165. The tap water in wash hand basin beside shower is very warm. I have taken the cover off the thermostat and there seems to be no adjustment. This seems to be [the shower I have](http://www.bestbathrooms.com/Stainless_Steel_Thermostatic_Shower_Panel/cid7443pr38135.html).

the thermostatic cartridge looks like 
[image]
i have turned the spindle as far anti clock wise as possible but only turns one full turn is there an other way to adjust it
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Shower valves normally have a mechanism for adjusting the maximum water temperature under the handle.  You'll have to consult the shower valve's manual for specifics.  If you don't have the manual, here's a picture of a typical shower valve. The red part of the valve is the temperature safety.  It is located under the shower handle and you rotate it to adjust the temperature.

[image]

Update:  [This document](http://www.bestbathrooms.com/content/BB-TRUSP303.pdf) seems to describe the procedure to adjust the temperature of your shower.  It looks relatively complex, but doable.

Comment: hi edwin i dont have a manual as i have just moved in but have taken the handle off and the spindle only turns one full turn.

Comment: See my updated answer.  I think the linked document should get you to hot water.

Comment: hi edwin i have tried that with no success. i am starting to wonder is the thermostat the problem or lack of water pressure as it isnt great c

Comment: Your shower valve could just be broken. Mineral buildup can sometimes interfere with the valve's operation. I had a shower valve that wouldn't allow any hot water to flow due to mineral buildup, and a soak overnight in vinegar fixed it.